# How to retrieve keywords within thousands of records from SQL Server 2008 fast?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Using the query function of entity collection in C# and it takes a long time to load the related records back from SQL Server 2008. Is there any fast way to do this? This is the query function I use:

```
 public void SearchProducts()
    {
        //Filter by search string array(searchArray)
        List<string> prodId = new List<string>();

        foreach (string src in searchArray)
        {
            StoreProductCollection prod = new StoreProductCollection();
            prod.Query.Where(prod.Query.StptName.ToLower() == src.ToLower() && prod.Query.StptDeleted.IsNull());
            prod.Query.Select(prod.Query.StptName, prod.Query.StptPrice, prod.Query.StptImage, prod.Query.StptStoreProductID);
            //  prod.Query.es.Top = 4;
            prod.Query.Load();

            if (prod.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (StoreProduct stpt in prod)
                {
                    if (!prodId.Contains(stpt.StptStoreProductID.ToString().Trim()))
                    {
                        prodId.Add(stpt.StptStoreProductID.ToString().Trim());
                        productObjectsList.Add(stpt);
                    }

                }
            }
         }
```

Comment: Yeah. They invented SQL queries for that. Possibly with table indexes. You can make indexes use case-insensitive collation, IIRC

Comment: Thanks..can you send me an example? I actually get the query collection but the Load() takes a long time..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, put an index on StptName column.

Second, if you need even better performance, write a Stored Procedure in SQL, to do your querying, and map it with Entity Framework.

Let me know if you need explanation on how to do any of the above.

A couple more micro-optimizations you can do if you don't want to write a Stored Procedure:

1. Write src.ToLower() in a temporary varaible, and than compare prod.Query.StptName.ToLower() to it.
2. By default, SQL Server queries are case insensitive, so check if that's the case, and if so, you can get rid of the ToLower altogether. You can change case sensitivity through Collation.

EDIT:
To create an Index:
Open the table designer in SQL Server Managment Studio.
Right click anywhere and select Indexes/Keys.
Click Add.
Under Columns add StptName.
Under Is Unique specify whether StptName is unique or not.
Under type select "index".
That's all!

As for mapping stored procedures - here's a nice tutorial:
http://www.robbagby.com/entity-framework/entity-framework-modeling-select-stored-procedures/

(You can jump straight to the "Map in the Select Stored Procedure" Section).

Comment: Hi there, thanks..Actually how can i map it with entity framework?And can i put an index on stptname column?if i did the index things, what the method can i use to do the query?

Answer (score 0):

You're hitting the database once per `searchArray` item, this is very wrong.
You might get better performance like this (have no way of testing it, give it a shot):

```
public void SearchProducts()
{
    //Filter by search string array(searchArray)
    List<string> prodId = new List<string>();
    StoreProductCollection prod = new StoreProductCollection();

    // Notice that your foreach() is gone

    // replace this
    // prod.Query.Where(prod.Query.StptName.ToLower() == src.ToLower() && prod.Query.StptDeleted.IsNull());
    // with this (or something similar: point is, you should call .Load() exactly once)
    prod.Query.where(prod.Query.StptDeleted.IsNull() && src.Any(srcArrayString => prod.Query.StptName.ToLower()==srcArrayString.ToLower());

    prod.Query.Select(prod.Query.StptName, prod.Query.StptPrice, prod.Query.StptImage, prod.Query.StptStoreProductID);
    //  prod.Query.es.Top = 4;
    prod.Query.Load();

    // ... rest of your code follows. 
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. But it returns a bool value and cannot be in the where clause to compile..prod.Query.where(prod.Query.StptDeleted.IsNull() && src.Any(srcArrayString => prod.Query.StptName.ToLower()==srcArrayString.ToLower());

Answer (score 0):

Given `List<string> searchArray` containing lowered words :

```
    public void SearchProducts()  
    {  
        //Filter by search string array(searchArray)  
        List<string> prodId = new List<string>();

        StoreProductCollection prod = new StoreProductCollection();  
        prod.Query.Where(searchArray.Contains(prod.Query.StptName.ToLower()) && prod.Query.StptDeleted.IsNull());  
        prod.Query.Select(prod.Query.StptName, prod.Query.StptPrice, prod.Query.StptImage, prod.Query.StptStoreProductID);  
        //  prod.Query.es.Top = 4;  
        prod.Query.Load();  

        if (prod.Count > 0)  
        {  
            foreach (StoreProduct stpt in prod)  
            {  
                if (!prodId.Contains(stpt.StptStoreProductID.ToString().Trim()))  
                {  
                    prodId.Add(stpt.StptStoreProductID.ToString().Trim());  
                    productObjectsList.Add(stpt);  
                }  

            }  
        }  
     }
```

This way you have only one query for all words.

Comment: I doubt OP's code assumes lowercase words in searchArray (he .ToLower()s both sides of the comparison)

Comment: He can easily create a new array with lowered words within the method if needed...

Comment: The following code causes an error and I need to search if the product name contains or like or equals to the string within the search array not in contrary?prod.Query.Where(searchArray.Contains(prod.Query.StptName.ToLower()) && prod.Query.StptDeleted.IsNull());